# iCloud document path at remote place and on local iPhone device - finding programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, icloud

1.I need to attach a text file named "document.doc" of iCloud to my configured mail id on my iPhone "programmatically"

2. What is the absolute path for icloud stored document with app ID
   is this file://localhost/private/var/mobile/Mobile documents/appId.com.companyname.appname/Documents/document.doc

if this is the path when I try to find the number of files in Documents under appId it's showing 0.

3. do iCloud documents stored in a local path when they opened? if so what is the exact absolute path of that local storage. I need to find this because I have to send the icloud document as an attachment programmatically

Answer (score 1):

Yes, iCloud documents are stored locally in your app's container in the Mobile Documents folder.

Is this a document that your app created? If so, you should use the methods Apple provides (namely, `-URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:`) to find out what the correct path is. You should not hard-code it as it might change over time.

If this file is in another app's container, then you're out of luck, since the sandbox won't let you access another app's files. (This might be why you're getting zero files there).